# How to filter contents of UITableView that has custom cell with Search Bar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am building iOS App using swift and Xcode version 6.3

I have created a tableview,searchbar as an outlet.

After that i created a new class ProjectTableviewCell as subclass of UITableview cell.

In my storyboard i connected multiple labels to prototype cell.

I implemented searchbar methods.And its filtering data in the tableviewcell properly.This all working fine.

In default before i search any content tableview displays list of contents.

After the filtering operation it displays only the particular filtered array only.

The problem now i am facing is in tableview cell contents is not displaying.

My Expected output is i want to show the filtered array with the existing cell contents in my tableview.

```
class myProjects: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var projectTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchProject: UISearchBar!
var project = [String]()
var searchActive : Bool = false

var filtered:[String] = []
//Search Bar Methods
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = project.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.projectTable.reloadData()
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(searchActive) {
        return filtered.count
        }
        return project.count;
    }



  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let textCellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! projectTableViewCell
    let row = indexPath.row

    if(searchActive){
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]

    } else {
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1)  as! UILabel).text = project[row] as String
    }
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(3)  as! UILabel).text = projectStatus[row] as String
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(7)  as! UILabel).text = ProjectDescription[row] as String
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(12) as! UILabel).text = category[row] as String
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(13) as! UILabel).text = subcategory[row] as String
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(14) as! UILabel).text = project_Tags[row] as String
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(15) as! UILabel).text = skill_Needed[row] as String
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(16) as! UILabel).text = budget[row] as String
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(17) as! UILabel).text = timeFrames[row] as String
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(18) as! UILabel).text = location[row] as String

    return cell
}
```

I am Beginner in Swift.Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It is recommended to make a Class of project rather than these numbers of arrays you have taken.

Comment: Yaa i understood just now i changed to a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the code as shown below.

```
struct Project {
    var title = ""
    var current_state = ""
    var description = ""
    var category_name = ""
    var subcategory_name = ""
    var tags = ""
    var skills = ""
    var budget = ""
    var estimated_time = ""
    var location = ""

    init(title: String, current_state: String, description: String, category_name: String, subcategory_name: String, tags: String, skills: String, budget: String, estimated_time: String, location: String){
        self.title = title
        self.current_state = current_state
        self.description = description
        self.category_name = category_name
        self.subcategory_name = subcategory_name
        self.tags = tags
        self.skills = skills
        self.budget = budget
        self.estimated_time = estimated_time
        self.location = location
    }
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let textCellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! projectTableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row

        if(searchActive){
            (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1)  as! UILabel).text = filtered[row].title as String
        }

        else {

            (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1)  as! UILabel).text = projectsArray[row].title as String
            (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(3)  as! UILabel).text = projectsArray[row].current_state as String
            (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(7)  as! UILabel).text = projectsArray[row].description as String
            (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(12) as! UILabel).text = projectsArray[row].category_name as String
            (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(13) as! UILabel).text = projectsArray[row].subcategory_name as String
            (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(14) as! UILabel).text = projectsArray[row].tags as String
            (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(15) as! UILabel).text = projectsArray[row].skills as String
            (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(16) as! UILabel).text = projectsArray[row].budget as String
            (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(17) as! UILabel).text = projectsArray[row].estimated_time as String
            (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(18) as! UILabel).text = projectsArray[row].location as String
        }
        return cell
    }
```